# How can I get current worker id in loopback?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, loopbackjs

When I run

```
NODE_ENV=production slc run
```

loopback will automatically start workers for each CPU core.

I want to run some code only once, but every worker runs it. How can I check what worker it is currently running in?

I noticed it is using [strong-supervisor](https://github.com/strongloop/strong-supervisor) behind the scenes to do its magic.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I solved it:

```
var cluster = require('cluster');

if (cluster.isMaster || (cluster.isWorker && cluster.worker.id == '1'))) {
    //Do stuff
}
```

Read more about cluster [here](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html)

Comment: This will be risky because if this worker get's crashed, no other worker will be there to do the stuff. Even if new worker is forked upon crash, new worker will not have id: `1`.